# Changing previous synchronous method to asynchronous

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, parallel-processing, async-await

I have a method called from within a program that authorizes card payment which was previously implemented in a synchronous way. However now I want to change it so it runs on a different thread so I can send cancel request once it has started.
It works, but I want to know if this is a good implementation, if there are some things I need to consider like deadlocks etc.
So here is a simplified version of my code:

```
public void Authorize()
{
    lock(object)
    {
        AuthorizeAsync();
    }
}

public async void AuthorizeAsync()
{
    // ...
    IProgress<string> progressHandler = new Progress<string>(progressString =>
    {
        UpdateProgressWindow(progressString.ToString());
    });
    cancellationToken = progressWindow.CancellationTokenSource.Token;
    progressWindow.show();
    results = await DoAuthorizeAsync(progressHandler, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
    // ...
}
```

I mainly want to use async - await because I want the authorization work to run separately from the UI thread so the user can still cancel the operation.
Do you suggest another approach other than async - await?
I am mainly concerned with the fact that I am calling an async method from sync method, I know the best practice is to use async all the way up but I cannot change the rest of the program.
The other concern I have is the lock in Authorize() could it pose any problem? I only want the code to be accessed by one thread at a time.
I am fairly new to this async - await architecture in .net so I'm pretty sure I didn't get it right on my first attempt.

Comment: Your `lock` statement is currently meaningless. Once `AuthorizeAsync` hits the `await` keyword, it will yield control back to your synchronous `Authorize` method, which will release the lock, but the operation hasn't completed yet. It also seems like you're using the async over sync anti-pattern. Can you show us your `DoAuthorizeAsync` call?

Comment: Returning `void` from an async method creates "fire and forget" behavior, you should try to avoid that and return `Task` or `Task<T>` instead.

Comment: @Yuval Itzchakov It is rather large complex method. DoAuthorizeAsync actually instantiates a class and calls a processPayment method from that object(which is not marked async). It
basicly sends a request to a POS device and then polls it for status until the operation is finished, then it gathers the results and returns it in a result object.